# This batch script does not echo out the value

Tags: bash-scripting

I have a strange problem with Windows batch script.

[image]

I don't understand where the error is, but what I can tell you is that, I did not put in mypersocom when asked to "Enter username :". It first started out with me trying to get `%useremail%` to echo out, but it wouldn't but it echo's out `%username%`, then it started doing what is seen in the screenshot.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Edit [it](http://superuser.com/posts/912255/edit), delete the image and paste the actual batch file contents. Then add what you input and the output you see. If you are facing a problem across multiple runs (as you've indicated in a comment below), mention the details of that as well clearly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment operation is wrong. It should be.

```
set olk=%tyuio%
```

In batch files to extract the value of a variable you need to place it in between `% %`. To assign a variable a value of another variable you need to extract the value of that variable and then assign it. Simply using the variable name is not enough.

Comment: That, not wrong. My bad, didn't comment the code properly.

// set variable olk to hold string 'tyuio'
set olk=tyuio
echo %olk%

Update on the code:

It seems the outputs output values, 3 sessions ago. So if I run, Natasha about 3 ~ 4 times, then it shows the output on the first time I ran Natasha. Its really hard to explain, because its not like a web-browser it doesn't have catch to clear, and the more I debug it, the more problems arise which leads me away from my original question.

which is:

I can't output %useremail%